# Understanding consumption units normalisation by $u^\prime (c) $

Tags: microeconomics, utility

It is frequently noted that if utility is given by $u(c)$, then the object
$$ \frac{u(c)}{u^\prime (c)} $$
puts the utility in consumption units via the normalisation by $u^\prime(c)$. What is the intuition behind this normalisation? Why are these now consumption units of utility?

Answer (score 6):

The derivative $u'(c)$ is defined as the limit of fractions of the form $\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta c}$, so $\frac{u(c)}{u'(c)}$ is of the form $\frac{u\,\Delta c}{\Delta u}$, which in terms of units reduces to units of consumption $c$ only.

Comment: +1. I see how the units cancel out but don't remember when do we actually use $\frac{u(c)}{u'(c)}$. Can you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @NicolasTorres I'm afraid I can't, as I don't recall ever having seen this "normalization" being used. Maybe the OP can help.